# Refining fnmatch pattern for more specific results

Tags: python, python-2.7

Brand new to Python, coming from MATLAB. Essentially no UNIX or regexp knowledge.

I have some data for processing sorted into folders. I'd like to get a list of files to process, so I prompt for a top level folder and search everything in that folder and subfolders for a match. Between the documentation for Python and various things here on SO I've gotten most of the way there:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
import tkFileDialog
import os
import fnmatch

def recursivedecodeprompt():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    toplevel = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(title='Select Top Level Directory')

    filelist = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(toplevel):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'LOG.*'):
            filelist.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

    return filelist
```

My question is in relation to the pattern string. My folders could have just a `LOG.001` file in them, or they could have `LOG.001`, `LOG.001.csv`, `LOG.001.gps`, etc., which my current pattern also matches. I thought I could be clever and use `'LOG.???'` but it returns the same list.

Is there a simple way to have `fnmatch` ignore files with anything appended after the 3 digit ID? Is there a more appropriate tool for the job?

Semi-related side question: Is there a way to allow the `tkFileDialog.askdirectory()` dialog to be resizable?

EDIT: To clarify, the numeric part of the filename can and will change, so I can have `LOG.001`, `LOG.002`, `LOG.003`, etc. I wish it was a less annoying naming convention but that's how it comes out of the device.

Comment: Try using re `re.findall("LOG.001.*",filenames)`, never used fnmatch but maybe the same expression can be used.

Comment: I don't think `re.findall()` can be used on a list

Comment: it can be used if you iterate over the list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm looking to exclude anything with another extension, so I only want `LOG.001`, `LOG.002`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using re:

```
filnames = ["LOG.001","LOG.002","LOG.001.csv","LOG.003.csv","LOG.1002"]
print [x for x in filnames if re.search("LOG.\d+$",x)]

['LOG.001', 'LOG.002', 'LOG.1002']
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you say it seems that only valid filenames are exactly seven characters long. So the simplest way would seem to be to include

```
if len(filename) != 7:
    continue
```

as the first line of the loop. This will terminate the current loop iteration unless the filename is indeed inly seven characters long. No regular expressions required!

Comment: the OP is looking for various log files that start with "LOG.001" and can end with .gps,.csv etc.. so I don't see how looking for the length is related to the question.

Comment: The OP specifically says (s)he wants to ignore any files which aren't just named "LOG.NNN" so as long as there are no "LOG.gps" files I don't see why this solution wouldn't work. The complaint appears to be that filenames like "Log.NNN.gps" are currently being matched. Or am I still misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @holdenweb yes I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I quite agree, but wanted to get you moving forward quickly before pointing out alternatives. @Padraic I have often done the same myself, no worries.

Comment: Ah, in fact I see Padraic has already provided the elegant way, so I'll just upvote his answer.